# Efficient way to program repeating alarms on Android, Java

Tags: java, android, alarm

From what I was told, there are several different ways of implementing in Java for Android devices what I want to accomplish, which is basically to do what the basic alarm functionality in most smartphones does, but in bulk. That is to say that instead of having alarms for 7:00, 7:05, 7:10, 7:15, and 7:20, you can just put a group of alarms between 7:00 and 7:20. I want this to have three main repeating options: specified days of the week, specified days of the month, and one specified day with no repetition. I am trying to solve this on my own, though I would like to see how other programmers go about this problem. Note that while I am somewhat experienced in Java, I'm not too experienced with Android development.

Comment: By the way this question has nothing to do with the Java Timer class (that should not be used in Android anyway)  so it's not a duplicate of the mentioned question.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to only schedule the next alarm of each group using [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Use `setExact()` in API 19+ and `set()` on older versions. It's required to use `setExact()` when targeting newer versions if you want the alarm to go off at the exact planned time.

When the alarm goes off it will wake up a registered [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), from which you can schedule the next alarm of the group, if any.

Comment: never tried that and it's not documented in the official docs but you can also (as i heard) wake up a Service, not only BroadcastReceiver

Comment: When you use a BroadcastReceiver you have the advantage that the system will create an implicit wake lock while you are handling the Intent. If you want to perform long-running operations in response to an alarm, you should use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver which starts an IntentService.